# Combine two arrays cocoa obj-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Given: ArrayOne = John, Bill, James, Adam

Given: ArrayTwo = Smith, Jones, Windsor, Newton

Result: ArrayThree = John Smith, Bill Jones, James Windsor, Adam Newton

Can't for the life of me figure it out. I can add ArrayTwo to the end of ArrayOne but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those are `NSString`s in your two arrays, just iterate through and create the combined string and add to a third array:

```
assert(arrayOne.count == arrayTwo.count);

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrayOne.count];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.count; ++i) {
    [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[i]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```